# How to set drop down 2nd levels to be open according to viewport size

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML and CSS code.

I want to know about how can I get my 3rd level drop down to open from the left side instead of from the right side.

```
    <div id="horizontalmenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="AboutUs.html">about us</a>
                    <ul>
                                            <li><a href="CEO_Message.html">Welcome Message</a></li>
                        <li><a href="VisionMission.html">Our Vision & Mission</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Objectives.html">Our Objectives</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Business_excellence.html">Business Excellence</a></li>
                        <li><a href="OurBoard.html">Our Board</a></li>
                        <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="Management.html">Musanada's Management</a>
                            <!--<ul>
                                <li><a href="#">second level</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">second level</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <span class="indicator2"></span>-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                </li>
                    <li><a href="Services.html">services</a>
                         <ul>
                                            <li><a href="DesignCoordination.html">Design and Coordination</a></li>
                        <li><a href="RoadsInfrastructure.html">Roads and Infrastructure</a></li>                    
                        <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="BuildingServices.html">Building Services </a>
                            <ul>                            
                                <li><a href="ProjectManagement.html">Project Management </a></li>

                                <li><a href="FacilitiesManagement.html">Facilities Management</a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <span class="indicator2"></span>
                        </li>
                             <li><a href="FacilityManagement.html">Facility Management</a></li>
                        <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="Overview.html">Procurement</a>
                            <ul>                            
                                <li><a href="Overview.html">Overview</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Musanada_Procurement_Process.html">Procurement Process</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Respond_to_Tender.html">Respond to a Tender</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ContactProcurement.html">Contact Procurement</a></li> 
                            </ul>
                            <span class="indicator2"></span>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                    </li>

                 <li><a href="OurProjects.html">Our project</a>
                         <ul>
                                            <li  class="Menu_second_level"><a href="BuildingOverview.html">Building</a>
                                                <!--<ul>
                                                    <li><a href="NationalRehabilitationCenter.html">National Rehabilitation Center</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="ZakherMosque.html">Zakher Mosque</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="ShootingClub.html">Shooting Club</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="CamelRaceTrackAlWathba.html">Camel Race Track Al Wathba</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="AbuDhabiAccountability.html">Abu Dhabi Accountability Authority Headquarters</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="CareRehabilitation.html">Care and Rehabilitation Center - Al Qua'a</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="GhayathiSpecialNeedsCenter.html">Ghayathi Special Needs Center</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="AlAinClub.html">Al Ain Ladies Club</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="AlShahamahSlaughterhouse.html">Al Shahamah Slaughter house</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="CivilDefenseAcademy.html">Civil Defense Academy</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="AbuDhabiClubProject.html">AbuDhabi Ladies Club Project</a></li>

                                                </ul>
                                                <span class="indicator2"></span>-->
                                            </li>
                        <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="EducationOverview.html">Education</a>
                            <!--<ul>
                                                    <li><a href="AbuDhabiFutureModelSchoolProgram.html">Abu Dhabi Future Model School Program</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="AlMiskKindergarten.html">Al Misk Kindergarten</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="KhnourFatimahBintAsadSchools.html">Khnour and Fatimah Bint Asad Schools</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="BinHamSchool.html">Bin Ham School – Al Wagan</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            <span class="indicator2"></span>-->
                        </li>                    
                        <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="HousingOverview.html">Housing</a>
                           <!-- <ul>                                                        
                                <li><a href="WataniProject.html">Watani Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="YasProject.html">Yas Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AlFalahVillages.html">Al Falah Villages</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AlShuaibahProject.html">Al Shuaibah Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AlShuwaibProject.html">Al Shuwaib Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AinAlFaydaProject.html">Ain Al Fayda Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="JebelHafeetProject.html">Jebel Hafeet Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="RamahProject.html">Ramah Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="MezyadUmmGhafaProject.html">Mezyad and Umm Ghafa Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="NeimahAlSalamatProject.html">Neimah and Al Salamat Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="BidaaAlMatawaProject.html">Bidaa Al Matawa’a Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="UmmAlAshtanProject.html">Umm Al Ashtan Project</a></li>                            
                            </ul>
                            <span class="indicator2"></span>-->
                        </li>

                             <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="HealthCareOverview.html">Health Care</a>
                                <!-- <ul>                            
                                     <li><a href="AlHayerAlYaharSuwaihanCenter.html">Al Hayer, Al Yahar and Suwaihan Center</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlRahbaHospital.html">Al Rahba Hospital</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlWaganHospital.html">Al Wagan Hospital</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlZafranaCenter.html">Al Zafrana Center</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="PreventiveMedicalCenter.html">Preventive Medical Center – Khalifa City</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="TawamDialysisCenter.html">Tawam Dialysis Center</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlHiliOudAlTawbahClinic.html">Al Hili and Oud Al Tawbah Clinic</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlTawayahMedicalCenter.html">Al Tawayah Medical Center</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlFalahClinic.html">Al Falah Clinic</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="KhalifaCityDialysisCenter.html">Khalifa City Dialysis Center</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlSilaHospital.html">Al Sila Hospital</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlAinHospital.html">Al Ain Hospital</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlMafraqHospital.html">Al Mafraq Hospital</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="GhayathiHospital.html">Ghayathi Hospital</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlMushrifCenter.html">Al Mushrif Center</a></li>
                                     <li><a href="AlNoorCentreforSpecialNeeds.html">Al Noor Centre for Special Needs</a></li>
                                     </ul>
                                 <span class="indicator2"></span>-->
                             </li>                         
                        <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="RoadInfrastructureOverview.html">Road & Infrastructure</a>
                          <!--  <ul>                            
                                <li><a href="SouthShamkhaProject.html">South Shamkha Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="PedestrianBridgesProject.html">Pedestrian Bridges Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="NeimaProject.html">Neima Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AlMafraqAlGhuwaifatHighwayProject.html">Al Mafraq – Al Ghuwaifat Highway Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AbuDhabiDubaiRoadProject.html">Abu Dhabi – Dubai Road Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="AbuDhabiAirportRoadProject.html">Abu Dhabi Airport Road Project</a></li>                            
                                <li><a href="MadinatZayedGhayathiRoad.html">Madinat Zayed – Ghayathi Road</a></li>                            
                            </ul>
                            <span class="indicator2"></span>-->
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                    </li>

                    <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="OurClient.html">clients</a>
                         <ul>                            
                                <li><a href="HelpDesk.html">800-177 Help Desk</a></li>                                                        
                             </ul>
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">partners</a></li>
                    <li><a href="MediaCenter.html">media</a>
                         <ul>                            
                                <li class="Menu_second_level"><a href="MusanadaNews.html">Musanada News</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li> <a href="MusanadaNewsletters.html">News Letters</a></li>
                                        <li> <a href="Contact_Us.html">Media Inquiry</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <span class="indicator2"></span>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="MediaGallery.html">Media Gallery</a></li>                                                        
                             </ul>
                        <span class="indicator"></span>
                    </li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://careers.musanada.com/">careers</a></li>
                <!--<li><a href="Contact_Us.html">contact us</a></li>-->

            </ul>
        </div>



Css
========================================================


#horizontalmenu {
/*width: 78%;*/
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}

        #horizontalmenu ul {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #horizontalmenu li a{
        font-family: 'dinmedium';
font-size: 12.1px;
padding:19px 0px 14px 39px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
        }

        #horizontalmenu li {
float: left;
position: relative;
padding: 0 0px;
display: block;
        }

#horizontalmenu li .indicator {display: block;position: absolute;color: #dedede;top: 23px;right: -12px;font-size: 17px;background: url('../images/nav_arrow.png') center center no-repeat;width: 8px;height: 7px;}

            #horizontalmenu li ul {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
            }

            #horizontalmenu li:hover ul {
                display: block;
                background:rgb(138, 0, 0);
                height: auto;
                /*width: 8em;*/
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                /*left: 10px;*/
                box-shadow:0 0 4px #757575;
            }

            #horizontalmenu li ul li {
                clear: both;
                border-style: none;
            }

#horizontalmenu ul li ul li.Menu_second_level ul {
    display:none;
position:absolute;
}

#horizontalmenu ul li ul li .indicator2 {display: block;position: absolute;color: #dedede;top: 17px;right: 10px;font-size: 17px;background: url('../images/2ndL_m_arrow.png') center center no-repeat;width: 8px;height: 7px;}
#horizontalmenu ul li ul li.Menu_second_level:hover ul {display:block;background:rgb(138, 0, 0);height: auto;margin:0;padding:0;box-shadow:0 0 4px #757575;left: 210px;top: 0; z-index: 1;}
#horizontalmenu ul ul li {margin: 0;width: 210px;}


            #horizontalmenu ul ul li a {

font-family: 'dinmedium';
font-size: 12px;
padding: 12px 0 12px 10px;
color: #fff;
text-align: left;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
-moz-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
-o-transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear;
            }

#horizontalmenu ul ul li:hover {
/*background: #fff;
color:#8a0000;*/
color: #FFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
}
#horizontalmenu ul li a:hover{color:#8a0000;}
#horizontalmenu ul ul li a:hover {/*color:#8a0000;*/ color:#fff;text-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #4B0000;}
```

Comment: I am new to stack please guys help me in my issue

Answer (score 1):

**Change the following `css` part:**

```
#horizontalmenu ul li ul li.Menu_second_level:hover ul {

    display:block;

    background:rgb(138, 0, 0);

    height: auto;

    margin:0;

    padding:0;

    box-shadow:0 0 4px #757575;

    right:100%; <-- delete left:210px

    top: 0;

    z-index: 1;

}
```

**Live Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/95qmoq4x/1/

Comment: Thanks for your coordination guys i have done my self with this css change #horizontalmenu ul li:nth-child(6) ul li.Menu_second_level:hover ul {display:block;background:rgb(138, 0, 0) !important;height: auto;margin:0;padding:0;box-shadow:0 0 4px #757575;left: -210px !important;top: 0; z-index: 1;}